# iphone sdk:how to convert arabic date format to english?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, nsdate

I am working on an application in which I save the current Date in the database but when my app runs in Arabic language the current date format is changed into Arabic. I mean the date format should be like this 09/02/2010 but the digits are converted to Arabic digits. So how do I convert them back to English digits even if my app running in the Arabic Language?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In general it's best to keep dates in an agnostic type and only format them when they must be displayed. A common format is storing the number of seconds since 1970, or another date you choose.

E.g. the following code will display the current time correctly formatted for the users local.

```
NSDate* now = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
NSString* localDateString = [formatter stringFromDate];
[formatter release];
```

However when you do have a date in a locale-specific format, you can again use the formatter class to convert it. E.g.

```
NSString* localDate = @"09/02/2010";  // assume this is your string

NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
NSDate* date = [formatter dateFromString: localDate];
[formatter release];
```

For working with any type of locale-specific data (dates, currency, measurements) then the formatter classes are your friend.

Comment: how do i change arabic locale to a fixed english locale?

Comment: Look at NSFormatter setLocale - you can pass in any locale identifier you wish.

Answer (score 6):

i found it here i did it like this

```
NSDate *CurrentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *Formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *indianLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[Formatter setLocale:indianLocale];
[Formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSString *FormattedDate=[Formatter stringFromDate:CurrentDate];
[indianLocale release];
[Formatter release];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"EST"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:localDate];
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift**

```
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US") as Locale!
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
let resultsDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
```